# php mssql while loop

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005, while-loop

I have an unusual issue with my while loop,

here is the code:

```
$link = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass);

if (!$link || !mssql_select_db($myDB, $link)) {
    die('Unable to connect or select database!');
}

$result = mssql_query("SELECT
TBL_1.FULLNAME AS FullName,
CAST(TBL_3.NOTE AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Note,
TBL_3.CREATEDATE AS CreateDate,
TBL_4.UNAME AS Creator
FROM
database.dbo.TBL_1 TBL_1,
database.dbo.TBL_2 TBL_2,
database.dbo.TBL_3 TBL_3,
database.dbo.TBL_4 TBL_4
WHERE
TBL_1.UID = TBL_2.UID AND
TBL_2.NOTEID = TBL_3.NOTEID AND
TBL_3.CREATORID = TBL_4.USERID AND
TBL_1.UID = '$id'
ORDER BY CreateDate desc") or die(mssql_get_last_message());

if (!mssql_num_rows($result)) {
                            echo '<tr>
                                    <td width="600px"> No results returned</td>
                                    </tr>';
                        } else {
                            while ($row =mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){                           
                            echo "<tr>
                                    <td width='15px'> ".++$counter." </td>
                                    <td width='600px'> ".$row['Note']." </td>
                                    <td width='185px'>".$row['CreateDate']."</td>
                                    <td width='185px'>".$row['Creator']."</td>
                                </tr>";
                                }
                    }
```

For majority of the records, everything is as expected.  In some cases though,  the while loop doesn't respond at all.  no errors, no text, just as if I never ran the command.

I tried searching and reading as much as I could, but without an error, its quiet difficult to find the solution.

Have tried using foreach instead, and it took a ton of scrubbing and cleaning to get it to not show 1 character per line.  Though it really just kept repeating the 1st record.

I should also point out that 1 of the rows is in RTF format, but I dont think that plays a role.

I'm connecting from a *nix machine to a MS SQL2005 server.

Thanks in advance for any and all advice!

Comment: View the page source of your output html.  What do you see?  You are not escaping the values for html output, so you may be getting broken markup . `htmlspecialchars($row['Note'])`

Comment: I see nothing at all, <table width="960px" border="1" align="center"></table>

Comment: Is there a way to halt the while loop to see the error code?  atleast to get an idea of whats causing this?

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Some other problem is likely causing a fatal error `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('disaply_errors', 1);`

Comment: Have reporting and logging of every error/notice enabled.  nothing shows up.  I've never seen anything like this when dealing with mysql, I'm leaning towards it having something to do with how MS Sql returns rows.  maybe too many characters?

Comment: As always, I forgot to add something that might be of importance,  var_dump($row) before the while loop shows the data.

Comment: The solution actually raises more questions than answers but it works (or maybe I'm just missing something here).  Seems the issue for some of the instances was the use of fetch_array/assoc on same $result.  I was using the same $result to get the first name before the table and that seems to have interfered.  Breaking it down into multiple queries IMO is far less elegant, but it seems to fix my immediate issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using freetds as drivers then some time with smalldate fields its create some issues you can do one thing to be sure go to you php.ini and try toggling

```
mssql.datetimeconvert = On
```

and in your freetds.conf file try to set

```html
client charset = UTF-8
text size = 1048576
```

this might be an issue, as you dont have any clue i face this issue and want to share with you.